# Column Name or Values supplied do not match table definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to allow my users to sign up in a form, the table where the data will be stored once the user clicks on the "sign up" button contains 2 foreign keys that can be NULL, however when the I try to submit a new sign up form, I get the error  *Column Name or number of supplied values does not match table definition* and I do not really know what the issue is. I have searched for a lot of solutions but none of them worked for this case. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
protected void signup_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strcon = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\Test\\Test\\App_Data\\database.mdf; Integrated Security = True";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    con.Open();

    String command = "INSERT INTO writer VALUES (@writer_Fn, @writer_Ln, @Age, @Username, @Password, @Email)";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(command, con);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@writer_Fn", first_box.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@writer_Ln", last_box.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", age_box.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user_box.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", confirm_box.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email_box.Text);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is the table definition of the "writer" table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[writer] 
(
    [writerID]    INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [writer_Fn]   CHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
    [writer_Ln]   CHAR (15)    NOT NULL,
    [Age]         INT          NULL,
    [Username]    VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    [Password]    VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    [Email]       VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    [tran_FID]    INT          NULL,
    [content_FID] INT          NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([writerID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_writer_content] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([content_FID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[content] ([ContentID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_writer_transaction] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([tran_FID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[transaction] ([tranID])
);
```

Comment: You need to insert null values in FK column using db.nullvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supplying the column names in your INSERT statement..

it should be:

```
INSERT 
INTO    writer (writer_Fn, writer_Ln, Age, Username, Password, Email)
VALUES (@writer_Fn, @writer_Ln, @Age, @Username, @Password, @Email)
```

Comment: Yes that was the reason, it worked now thanks a lot! :)